# Serverless lambda Global Environmental Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am playing with serverless, and I am trying to figure out how to rewrite this serverless.yml file so I don't duplicate the environmental variables for each function. Is there a way to set environmental variables globally?

```
service: test-api
frameworkVersion: ">=1.2.0 <2.0.0"
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  timeout: 30
  stage: dev
  memorysize: 2048
  region: us-east-2
  logRetentionInDays: 21

functions:
  doCreate:
    handler: functions/do-create.handler
    environment:
      DB_PORT: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/db_port}
      DB_URL: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/db_url}
      API_KEY: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/api_key}
      ENV: "${self:custom.stage}"
      SEARCH_ARN: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/search_arn}
  doUpdate:
    handler: functions/do-update.handler
    environment:
      DB_PORT: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/db_port}
      DB_URL: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/db_url}
      API_KEY: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/api_key}
      ENV: "${self:custom.stage}"
      SEARCH_ARN: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/search_arn}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just simply move them into the `provider` section. They will be applied to all functions in the same service.

```
service: test-api
frameworkVersion: ">=1.2.0 <2.0.0"
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  timeout: 30
  stage: dev
  memorysize: 2048
  region: us-east-2
  logRetentionInDays: 21
  environment:
    DB_PORT: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/db_port}
    DB_URL: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/db_url}
    API_KEY: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/api_key}
    ENV: "${self:custom.stage}"
    SEARCH_ARN: ${ssm:/${self:custom.stage}/search_arn}
functions:
  doCreate:
    handler: functions/do-create.handler
  doUpdate:
    handler: functions/do-update.handler
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Globals section in the SAM template

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs12.x
    Timeout: 180
    Handler: index.handler
    Environment:
      Variables:
        TABLE_NAME: data-table
```

For more details please go through this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy-globals.html

Comment: Do you have an example of how to convert this to serverless.yml?